# Can I use UML to diagram ERDs?

Tags: database-design, uml, modeling

1) Can I use UML to diagram ERDs?
2) If answer to 1 is "yes", the use of UML is standardized and widely used for that purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model#Diagramming_conventions), yes you use UML to represent Entity-Relationship models but I don't think it's too common. I think the more common one is Crow's Foot notation.

Comment: Here is example of Crow's Foot: http://www.information-management.com/issues/20020501/5170-1.html?zkPrintable=true

This is quite different than UML, but UML works well if you want to use Class diagrams

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for example Visual UML (Visual Object Modelers) would simply offer *Relational Table* as a class stereotype.
However, it may depend on the tool, so try it out first. For example, see **[Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/)**.

Answer (score -1):

I found a databse UML modeling workaround with EclipseUML Omondo. I just need to write my stereotypes and immediately get my annotations in the java code. The annotated code is then used with Hibernate mapper in order to create my database.
It works really well and easy to use :-)

This is a top down approach from model to database using stereotype in the class diagram with live annotations synchronization between the diagram and the code. I never seen any other tool except Omondo doing this live java annotation synchronization and this is for me really superb :-)